# Using the equation of a line between two points on an rational curve to find the equation of the curve

Tags: geometry, curves

I'm a little confused on the way this question is phrased - basically I know the equation of my rational curve is $y^2(1 + x) = (1 - x)^3$ or $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{(1 - x)^3}{(1 + x)}}$ and I know the slope of a line connecting two points $(x, f(x))$ and (1,0) such that $0 \leq x \leq 1$ is uniquely determined by the equation $\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + x}$

So, I'm supposed to use this fact to work backwards to $y^2(1 + x) = (1 - x)^3$

Any idea on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: The curve with equation $y^2(1+x)=(1-x)^3$ is a rational curve, not an elliptic curve.

Comment: I'm missing something. You talk about *the slope of a line connecting two points*. But $(x,y)$ is just a single point?!? Did you, perhaps, mean that the slope of the tangent of the curve at $(x,y)$ is $\sqrt{1-x^2}/(1+x)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen no, it was just stupidity of notation on my part. You just evaluate the slope equation for an x between 0 and 1 and it gives you the slope of the line connecting the point f(x) for that same x and the point (1,0) , where f(x) is the rational curve.

Comment: The slope $m$ of the line connecting the points $(x_1,y_1)=(x,f(x))$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(1,0)$ is
$$m=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}=\frac{f(x)-0}{x-1}.$$
Therefore $y=f(x)=(x-1) m.$ You can take it from here.

Comment: you say first that $f$ is a curve then you write $(x,f(x))$ so $f$ becomes a function (to never appear again), then you add a condition on $y$ even though it doesn't appear, and then you say that some expression is an equation, but the equal sign is not seen anywhere. Then in the comments you say $f(x)$ is a point... you are mixing up so many things it's impossible to follow.

Comment: It's a convoluted problem. I'm given $y^2(1+x)=(1−x)^3$ and that $Y =  \frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + x} (X - 1)$ where $X, Y$ are points on the line connecting (1,0) and $(x, f(x))$ - I want to work backwards from $Y =  \frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + x} (X - 1)$ to $y^2(1+x)=(1−x)^3$ - I adjusted some things in the original post to clarify things.

Comment: What are the upper case $Y$ and $X$? Where did they come from? Or are they the same as $y$ and $x$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen they are the X and Y plane, and the x and y are for describing the cissoid, and the X and Y coordinates describe points on the line connecting two points on the cissoid. I did not choose this notation.